# Split a big table on two pages

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I'm trying to fix a table in my latex file. The table is too long and few last rows go over the number of pages and also partially into the footnote. I thought of using `longtable` package to break the table and extend over the second page (see example 1). However, once I do it I run into another problem because the text in the right column goes beyond the `\textwidth`. No clue how to overcome this problem.

In the end, I would prefer to have the big table stretched over two pages with the header of the table also visible on the second page. I would appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newlength{\asdf} 
\setlength{\asdf}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\asdf}{-8\tabcolsep}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{YYYYYYYYYYYY}  & \textbf{ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ} \\
\midrule
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
 0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xlu8.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you are. With `ltablex`, the syntax is the same as for `longtable`. In particular, you don't nest `tabularx` in a `table` environment, and the `\caption` is incorporated to the first head.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\caption{My caption} \\
\toprule
\textbf{YYYYYYYYYYYY} & \textbf{ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\textbf{YYYYYYYYYYYY} & \textbf{ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize( To be continued)}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
 0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
 0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The (To be continued) part that you included in the code is something that looks really good, to my surprise. Thank you for that

Comment: I just realized I might have another question. Since my table is incorporated in the text it looks like the `float` is not helping me to determine the position of the table. I tried to add `[t]` in order to start the table at the top of the page: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}lcX@{}}` but the table doesn't move an inch. Any idea why and what can I do?

Comment: @Jo-Achna: To have it float it must be inserted in a table environment: `begin{table}[!t]\begin{tabularx}...`. The `[t]` that goes with `tabularx` denotes the alignment w.r.t. the current line.

Comment: I thought so but once doing it I receive the warning message `Text page 14 contains only floats`. It looks like once one problem is solved another one appears.

Comment: That's probably because you have too many floats on this page. Normally some should go to the next page. See if this [link](https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html) helps.

Answer (score 5):

A table that is inside a `table` environment can not be broken onto several pages, which is why the table in your example image is continued and overlaps with the footnote and page number.

In order to get a table that breaks across pages and has the variable with `X` type columns from the `tabularx` package, you could use the `ltablex` package as shown in the following example. To repeat the header on all following pages, you can use the `\endhead` command as shown in the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{ltablex}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{YYYYYYYYYYYY}  & \textbf{ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ} \\
\midrule
\endhead
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
 0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
  0000 & aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb;aaaa $\&$ bbbbb; \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. I not knew `ltablex` package. +1.

Comment: The answer is exactly what I was looking for. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I want to draw a table exactly like this. It means that my table is long and it is necessary to move the continuation of the table to the next page. But I used each of these packages and it didn't work. can you please help me ,Thanks.

```
\documentclass[msc]{thesis}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{supertabular}  
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[algosection,lined,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}%


\begin{table}[]
    \label{features}
    \caption{ تفسیر کامل ویژگی‌های دیتاست }
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{clclc}
                \hline
                \textbf{No.}             & \textbf{Feature}                                         & \textbf{Type}                    & \textbf{Description}                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & \textbf{} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumDots}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of dots in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SubdomainLevel}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the level of subdomain in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                               &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PathLevel}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the depth of the path in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{UrlLength}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the total characters in the webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                             &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumDash}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “-” in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                    &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumDashInHostname}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “-” in hostname part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AtSymbol}                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if “@” symbol exist in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                  &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TildeSymbol}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if “∼” symbol exist in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                  &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumUnderscore}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “\_” in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumPercent}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “\%” in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumQueryComponents}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of query parts in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                            &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumAmpersand}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “\&” in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumHash}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of “\#” in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumNumericChars}                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of numeric characters in the webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                 &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NoHttps}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if HTTPS exist in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                                       &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{16} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RandomString}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if random strings exist in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                              &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{17} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{IpAddress}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if IP address is used in hostname part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                               &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{18} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{DomainInSubdomains}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if TLD or ccTLD is used as part of subdomain in webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                         &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{DomainInPaths}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if TLD or ccTLD is used in the path of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                  &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{20} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HttpsInHostname}                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if HTTPS in obfuscated in hostname part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                              &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{21} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HostnameLength}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the total characters in hostname part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{22} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PathLength}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the total characters in path of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                         &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{23} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{QueryLength}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the total characters in query part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{24} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{DoubleSlashInPath}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if “//” exist in the path of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                            &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{NumSensitiveWords}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Counts the number of sensitive words (i.e., “secure,” “account,” “webscr,” \\ “login,” “ebayisapi,” “signin,” “banking,” “confirm”) in webpage URL\end{tabular}}                                 &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{26} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{EmbeddedBrandName}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Checks if brand name appears in subdomains and path of webpage URL. \\ Brand name here is assumed as the most frequent domain name in the webpage\\ HTML content\end{tabular}}                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{27} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PctExtHyperlinks}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Continuous}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the percentage of external hyperlinks in webpage HTML source code}                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{28} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PctExtResourceUrls}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Continuous}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the percentage of external resource URLs in webpage HTML source code}                                                                                                                                                &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{29} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ExtFavicon}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Checks if the favicon is loaded from a domain name that is different from the \\ webpage URL domain name\end{tabular}}                                                                           &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{InsecureForms}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if the form action attribute contains a URL without HTTPS protocol}                                                                                                                                                  &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{31} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RelativeFormAction}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if the form action attribute contains a relative URL}                                                                                                                                                                &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{32} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ExtFormAction}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if the form action attribute contains a URL from an external domain}                                                                                                                                                 &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{33} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AbnormalFormAction}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Check if the form action attribute contains a “\#,” “about: blank,” an empty \\ string, or javascript:true\end{tabular}}                                                                         &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{34} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PctNullSelfRedirectHyperlinks}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Continuous}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Counts the percentage of hyperlinks fields containing empty value, self-redirect \\ value such as “\#,” the URL of current webpage, or some abnormal value \\ such as “file://E:/”\end{tabular}} &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{35} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{FrequentDomainNameMismatch}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Checks if the most frequent domain name in HTML source code does not\\ match the webpage URL domain name\end{tabular}}                                                                           &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{36} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{FakeLinkInStatusBar}                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Checks if HTML source code contains JavaScript command onMouseOver to\\ display a fake URL in the status bar\end{tabular}}                                                                       &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{37} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{RightClickDisabled}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Checks if HTML source code contains JavaScript command to disable right\\ click function\end{tabular}}                                                                                           &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{38} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PopUpWindow}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if HTML source code contains JavaScript command to launch pop-ups}                                                                                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{39} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SubmitInfoToEmail}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Check if HTML source code contains the HTML “mailto” function}                                                                                                                                                              &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{40} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{IframeOrFrame}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if iframe or frame is used in HTML source code}                                                                                                                                                                      &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{41} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{MissingTitle}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if the title tag is empty in HTML source code}                                                                                                                                                                       &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{42} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ImagesOnlyInForm}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Binary}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Checks if the form scope in HTML source code contains no text at all but images only}                                                                                                                                       &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{43} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SubdomainLevelRT}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the number of dots in hostname part of webpage URL}                                                                                                                                                                  &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{44} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{UrlLengthRT}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Counts the total characters in the webpage URL. Apply rules and thresholds to \\ generate value\end{tabular}}                                                                                    &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{45} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PctExtResourceUrlsRT}                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Counts the percentage of external resource URLs in webpage HTML source code}                                                                                                                                                &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{46} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{AbnormalExtFormActionR}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Check if the form action attribute contains a foreign domain, “about:blank” or\\ an empty string\end{tabular}}                                                                                   &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{47} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ExtMetaScriptLinkRT}                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Categorical counts percentage of meta, script and link tags containing external \\ URL in the Attributes\end{tabular}}                                                                           &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{48} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{PctExtNullSelfRedirect-HyperlinksRT} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Categorical} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Counts the percentage of hyperlinks in HTML source code that uses different \\ domain names, starts with “\#,” or using “JavaScript:: void(0)”\end{tabular}}                                     &           \\ \cline{1-4}
                &                                                          &                                  &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &           \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}%
            
        }

    \end{center}

\end{table}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261709)